# Password protect a Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, passwords

Is there a way to secure a Google Sheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your spreadsheets are already all password protected, in that one must log in with their google account (and thus password) to view the spreadsheet. You can control who may access the spreadsheet by clicking on the "share" button in the upper right and editing what permissions users with access to the spreadsheet are given.

Comment: The only problem is people who dont have gmail accouts need to be able to edit the spreadsheet.

Comment: Ah. Unfortunately, there isn't any way to control access unless you either make it open to everybody or else they sign up for a google account. One doesn't need a gmail account specifically though; you can sign up for a google account with your existing email.

Comment: You can make it accessible only by people who have a link.  This security through obscurity: the link is very long and very hard to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the Google script from here to have a password-protected spreadsheet. It gives you two options - encrypt and decrypt. You can set a password and if the password is wrong, all you will see is obfuscated text.

- http://www.skipser.com/p/2/p/password-protect-google-drive-document.html
- https://techzama.com/how-to-password-protect-google-sheet/

nhingle's answer is correct, but most people are logged into Google 24 hours a day on phones and PCs. That means if somebody has access to these momentarily, they have full access to Google docs as well.

Comment: People able to run scripts from a custom menu have editor access and people having editor access have access to the spreadsheet version history so this isn't secure.

Comment: @user0 did you perhaps copy the link from the other post here? That was spam. You might want to revert it here